# QPainter keep previous drawings

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

This is my first time using Qt and I have to make a MSPaint equivalent with Qt. I am however having trouble with painting my lines. I can currently draw a line by clicking somewhere on the screen and releasing somewhere else, however when I draw a second line the previous line is erased. How could I keep the previously painted items when painting another item?

```
void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe){
    QWidget::paintEvent(pe);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawPicture(0,0,pic);
}

void Canvas::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mp){
    start = mp->pos();
}

void Canvas::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *mr){
    end = mr->pos();
    addline();
}

void Canvas::addline()Q_DECL_OVERRIDE{
    QPainter p(&pic);
    p.drawLine(start,end);
    p.end();
    this->update();
}
```

Canvas is a class that derives QWidget, it has 2 QPoint attributes start and end.

Class body:

```
class Canvas : public QWidget{
Q_OBJECT
private:
    QPoint start;
    QPoint end;
    QPicture pic;
public:
    Canvas(){paint = false;setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents);}
    void addline();
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void  mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * );
    //void  mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * );
    void  mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent * );

};
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're creating a new QPainter variable each time you add a new line which causes the previous QPainter variable stored to be destroyed since it has left scope (but due to the nature of OpenGL, it's kept in the framebuffer anyway). Try having QPainter a class-scope variable and see if that helps.

Comment: @Poriferous - it doesn't matter, `pic` is his buffer, the painter should not affect the buffer data. This doesn't mean keeping the painter is a bad idea.

Comment: @anaBad - what is `pic`? Show us the body of your widget class.

Comment: `pic` would be `QPaintDevice` which is what `QPainter` isn't being drawn to. Hence my theory that it's a scope issue.

Comment: @Poriferous - but from his code it seems like `pic` has class scope. It should persist between different calls. From the code posted so far I see nothing that would clear `pic`.

Comment: If that's the case, then there might be an implementation flaw with `pic`'s reimplemented `paintEngine()` function. Until we get more info, we can't help further.

Comment: Added the class body.

Comment: @anaBad is there a particular reason you are using a `QPicture`? Try changing that to a `QPixmap`

Comment: I tried with QPixmap and QImage but I keep getting the following error:
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QPicture` records `QPainter` commands. Also from its documentation you can read this:

> Note that the list of painter commands is reset on each call to the
>   QPainter::begin() function.

And the `QPainter` constructor with a paint device does call `begin()`. So each time the old recorded commands are deleted.

It may sound tempting to use it, since it does say a few good things, for example, that it is resolution independent, but this is not how drawing applications work in reality. Switch to a `QPixmap` and your drawings will persist.

Also, don't forget to initialize the pixmap, because by default it will be empty and you will not be able to draw on it.

```
Canvas() : pic(width,height) {...}
```

Furthermore, if you would like the introduce the concept of brushes as in artistic brushes and not `QBrush`, you might want to look at this [approach to draw the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502611/line-interpolation-in-qt).

EDIT: Note that you should be able to prevent `QPicture` from losing its content by not calling `begin()` on it more than once. If you create a painter, dedicated to only drawing on it at class scope, and call begin in the constructor, different recorded drawing operations should persist. But as their number increases it will take more and more time to draw the `QPicture` to your widget. You could come around that by using both a `QPicture` and a `QPixmap`, and draw to both, use the picture to record the actions and the pixmap to avoid continuously redrawing the picture, even though you will do double the work it will still be more efficient, while you still retain the possibility to use the picture to re-rasterize in a different resolution or save the drawing history. But I doubt `QPicture` will do well as your drawing application begins to take shape of an actual drawing application, for example when you start using pixmap brushe stencils and such.